# How to implement group of images?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, collections, tableview

I am making social app and I have place there I need to make 6 images on page. In this place usually I gave text or one image. How can I set multi images in that place now?

I want set frame for this place and then I want that images scaled to my frame. Is it possible and that element I need to use here? UICOllections or that?

Comment: I do not understand your question at all. can you please rephrase and elaborate?

Comment: you question is not that clear to help.. if possible update question or show some images what you need... if you have tried any code paste here.. so that it will be easy for us to help you

Comment: Question is not clear,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I understood from your question you'll need to use UICollectionView.
Your should follow these steps:

1. Make an NSArray of all your images.
   Ex. NSArray *imageArray=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"image1.png",@"image2.png",@"image3.png", nil];
2. Drag a UICollectionView to your storyboard, create a custom cell, and use a UIImageView on that custom cell.
3. Assign a new class to your custom cell.
4. Connect an outlet for image view in your custom cell's class.
5. Connect delegate and datasource of your UICollectionView.
6. Use the following delegate methods for UICollectionView:

   ```
   -(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:
   (UICollectionView *)collectionView
   {
   return 1;
   }

   -(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
       numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
   {
   return imageArray.count;
   }

   -(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
   {
   CustomCellClass *myCell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MyCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

   UIImage *image;
   int row = [indexPath row];
   image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageArray[row]];
   myCell.imageview.image = image;

   return myCell;
   }
   ```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Is there way to use it without storyboards?